# How do I write custom binding for WCF Service using code?

Tags: wcf, custom-binding

How do I write custom binding for WCF Service and include it with the service.
I need to do it with code not in config file.

If I write a custom binding then how do I include the new binding in my WCF Service? Currently I know how to do it in config, but how do I do this in code? or after creating custom binding then how do I make my WCF service to use the new binding?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793.aspx

Comment: If I write a custom binding then how do I include the new binding in my WCF Service? Currently I know how to do it in config, but how do I do this in code? or after creating custom binding then how do I make my WCF service to use the new binding?